# just-audio - Listen to audio complete

Tags: just-audio

I'm trying to listen to a stream to find out when an audio has com to an end.

```
  player.playbackEventStream.asBroadcastStream().listen((data) {
    print("Event: ${data.toString()}");
  },onDone: () {
    print("Done:");
  })
```

It only fires once...
I tried the diffrent streams, but could not find anything suitable.

Comment: `if(data.updatePosition == data.duration){print("End of Song"); }`

Seems to be broadcasted at the end

Comment: This also works:
`player.processingStateStream.asBroadcastStream().listen((data) { if(data == ProcessingState.completed){ print("End of Song"); }});`

Comment: Hi Martin, I have written an answer for you below. Can you please check whether it answers your question? I can't point duplicates here until it is accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different events you might want to listen to:

1. Auto-advancing to the next playlist item after reaching the end of the current one.
2. Completing playback when reaching the end of the last item in the playlist.

To listen for auto-advancing:

```dart
player.positionDiscontinuityStream.listen((discontinuity) {
  if (discontinuity.reason == PositionDiscontinuityReason.autoAdvance) {
    print('Finished current track, continuing onto next');
  }
});
```

To listen to playback completion:

```dart
player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
  if (state == ProcessingState.completed) {
    print('Reached end of last item - playback completed');
  }
});
```

If you only have a single item to play, and you are not looping, then you only need to listen to the second event.